# Yahoo AdCrawler hammering our site

Tags: web-crawler

Yahoo AdCrawler is re-trying some URLs repeatedly.  The URLs are being given a 302 response code, so I suppose Yahoo should come back and try again "later", but "later" in my book doesn't mean that 7 specific URLs should be hit 3,000 times a day each.

The URLs are of the style:

```
/find/product-abc123?ppcid=yahoo_PPC_Product
```

The Query part may well be something our Client has added, but I mention it in case it rings any bells

We've banned AdCrawler in Robots.txt for now.

```
User-agent: Yahoo!-AdCrawler
Disallow: /
```

If you have any thoughts, similar experiences, or ideas I'd appreciate them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdCrawler is NOT the same as Slurp, which is what Yahoo uses to build their index.  [AdCrawler](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/ysm/sps/ysmmanage/permlinks/yahoo_adcrawler.html) is:

> Recently, Yahoo! launched another
>   crawler (named “Yahoo!-AdCrawler”)
>   that also will crawl YSM advertiser
>   landing pages. This crawler is
>   designed to help us make relevance
>   assessments of these pages, that helps
>   us match ads to specific search
>   queries.

Its perfectly safe for you to block it--and is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks. The description on their site suggests it should not hammer a URL. I wonder if I have something set up wrongly on my site - which  might cause other problems of course - in particular if no one else has seen this behaviour from AdCrawler

Comment: Based on the comments I've seen elsewhere, it sounds like AdCrawler is generally a pain and not well received.  There were some blog posts claiming they wasted gigabytes of bandwidth a month to AdCrawler specifically.

Comment: I've come to that conclusion too. Its banned ...